# UI部品が表示されたりされなかったりします。

Tags: ios, objective-c

objective-cをつかっています。FirstViewControllerでparseのsignup処理を行ってからsecondVCに遷移させています。secondVCにはlabel,button,tableView,imageViewがあります。tableViewとimageViewは毎回描画されるのですが、labelとbuttonは描画されないことが多々あります。なぜでしょうか？

---FirstViewController---

```
-(void)moveToSecontVC{
PFUser *user = [PFUser currentUser];
NSError *error = nil;
[user signUp:&error];
if(!error){
    SecondViewController *SecondVC = [[SecondViewController alloc] init];
    [self presentViewController:createProfileVC animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
}
```

---SecondViewController---

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(30, 80, 260, 0)];
label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
label.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
label.text = @"text";
[self.view addSubview:label];


UITableView *tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 200, self.view.frame.size.width, 88)];
tableView.delegate = self;
tableView.dataSource = self;
tableView.allowsSelection = NO;
tableView.scrollEnabled = NO;
[self.view addSubview:tableView];

UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(30, 296, 260, 60)];
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(pushedContinue) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"button"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.view addSubview:button];

UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(115,90,90,90)];    
imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image"];
[self.view addSubview:imageView];

}
```

---追記---
recursiveDescriptionを確認したところ、どうやらaddSubViewはされているようでした。また、buttonのあるべきところをタップするとbuttonが見えるようになりました。

Comment: `addSubview`できていないのか、追加されたビューが不可視なのか切り分けるために、ビュー追加後に`recursiveDescription`でビューの状態を取得してみるのはどうでしょうか？

Comment: moveToSecontVCメソッドはどのような過程を経て呼び出されていますか？SecondVCではviewWillAppear/viewDidAppearは実行されますか？

Answer (score 1):

```
UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(30, 80, 260, 0)];
```

`label`の高さが`0`になっています。このままでは目に見えません。

`button`については、おそらくリソースからイメージの取得を失敗しているのではないかと想像されます。イメージではなく、テキストにしてみると、どうなりますか？

```
UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(30, 296, 260, 60)];
[button setTitle: @"Button" forState: UIControlStateNormal];
```

Comment: すみません、コードを削りすぎました。サイズ指定等はしてあります。なので、きちんと描画されるときもあります。

Comment: @shipaaan 早計な判断をしてしまい、申しわけありません。コードの書き換えをしていただきましたので、当該コメントは削除いたしました。